Swiper React: Swiping Not Working with Dynamic Slides
I try to use swiper.js to make navigation infinite from dynamic array holding swipe data.
But what happens is that navigation to right is not working at all, and navigation to the left works on oposite direction
Here is my code
import React from "react";
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import {Navigation, Pagination} from "swiper/modules";

function DynamicSwiperExample() {
    const numberOfSLides = 5

    const slides = []
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfSLides; i++) {
        slides.push(`Slide ${i + 1}`)
    }
    console.log("Slides", slides)
    return (
        <Swiper
            spaceBetween={10}
            slidesPerView={3}
            loop={true}
            pagination={{
                clickable: true,
                dynamicBullets: true,
            }}
            breakpoints={{
                0: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                },
                520: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 3,
                },
                992: {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                },
                1198: {
                    slidesPerView: 5,
                },
            }}
            navigation={true}
            modules={[Pagination, Navigation]}
            className="mySwiper mt-4"

        >
            {slides.map((slide, index) => (
                <SwiperSlide key={index}>{slide}</SwiperSlide>
            ))}
        </Swiper>
    );
}

export default DynamicSwiperExample

